# How to check for dynamic route segment from view

Tags: ember.js

I have a datepicker UI widget and I'm trying to keep it in sync with my routes. The routes are pretty straightforward:

```
/months
/months/Jan-2013
/months/Feb-2013
...
```

I'm having a hard time updating the datepicker if the user starts out by entering one of the dynamic routes (e.g. `/months/Jan-2013`).

How can I do this? Unfortunately, to change the date I need to use the datepicker's API (i.e. I can't use a handlerbars helper and just update the HTML), so I think I'll need a custom function in my view. I've tried using observed properties, without success.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
App.MonthRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
        this.controllerFor('application').set('activeMonth', model.get('id'));
    }
});
```

Now my `ApplicationController` always knows the 'selected month'. I can use this in my datepicker view's init to set the date correctly:

```
App.DatepickerView = Ember.View.extend({

    didInsertElement: function() {
        var _this = this;

        $('#dp').datepicker({
            'format': 'M yyyy',
            'minViewMode': 'months',
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
            var id = $(this).datepicker().data('date').replace(" ", "-"),
                month = App.Month.find(id);

            _this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('month', month);

        });

        // right here:
        if (this.get('controller.activeMonth')) {
            $('#dp').datepicker('setDate', this.get('controller.activeMonth'));
        }

    }

});
```

Any other answers/suggestions welcome.